# MongoDB Aggregate multiple local fields on $lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I'm using an aggregate to get 4 child Documents per each Parent Doc. The child documents are all from the same Collection though.

```
   [
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'Roles', 
      'localField': 'dentistId', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'DENTIST'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'Roles', 
      'localField': 'doctorId', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'DOCTOR'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'roles', 
      'localField': 'lawyerId', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'LAWYER'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'roles', 
      'localField': 'ceoId', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'CEO'
    }
  }
]
```

I'm using a version of MongoDB > 4. I'm looking to just have 1 `$lookup` and then do something like

```
localField: { $in:[dentistId, doctorId, lawyerId, ceoId }
```

Is there any way to consolidate this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can add a field `childDocs`, and push all ids in it,
- pass that field in `localField`

```
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      childDocs: [
        "$dentistId",
        "$doctorId",
        "$lawyerId",
        "$ceoId"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'roles', 
      'localField': 'childDocs', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'childDocs'
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Is there any way to guarantee the order of the returned roles? I.e, Given your example above, it'd be great if `childDocs` (from $lookup) Array was dentist,doctor,lawyer,ceo (so the order that childDocs in $addFields is

Comment: No it will not guarantee the order of document as per input ids. but i can say the order of return document would same as that is currently in actual collection, i.e 4 documents in a collection in order `[1,2,3,4]`, if i query using `{ field: { $in: [1,2] } }` it will return `[1,2]`, if i query using `{ field: { $in: [2,1] } }` it will return same as first query `[1,2]`, return same order that is present in actual collection.